# having repeated trouble with MySQL and Snow Leopard - Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35

Tags: mysql, macos

I don't know very much about server maintenance and am trying to learn by managing my own Mac. I'm running a local rails application with a MySQL database (5.5.9). All has been well for a long time UNTIL I attempted to start a new rails project. At that time, I ran bundle install, which updated my mysql gem from 0.2.6 to 0.3.6. Ever since then, or I'm associating with that (it may be that I also installed RVM around that time), I can't startup my MySQL server. I get the following error:

```
Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
```

repeatedly. I've tried fixing with:

```
mv ibdata1 ibdata1.bak
cp -a ibdata1.bak ibdata1
```

which works (reference: http://cglreport.zhenhua.info/2008/08/mysql-error-unable-to-lock-ibdata1.html)  (I have to do it on a few other files too), but it only works for a while. When I restart, or periodically the problem comes back. What's going on ? This doesn't seem to be a reasonable solution to me. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: then the error becomes: Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: 3036 Address already in use. Weird - help!!!!

Comment: running "top" command shows nothing running on 3036 btw

Comment: `top` wouldn't tell you anything about port numbers.

Comment: really? When I run "top" it tells me a port# in the list. What can I do to find the offending process?

Comment: That's the number of Mach ports the process is using, not the port number(s) it's listening on.

Comment: @panzhuli  `sudo lsof -i :3036`

Comment: Try ending the process in activity monitor...I had the same problem and after ending all mysql instances and restarting them it worked fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That sounds pretty convincingly like you already have an instance of your MySQL server running, and you're trying to steal a data file that it's using.

Comment: is there a way to ask the system what's running on port 3036? I don't see anything there when running "top" from the terminal. I think this is a limitation of my knowledge here...

Comment: Probably easier to just look for `ps ax|grep mysql`. For posterity, though, try `lsof -np|grep :mysql`. (`lsof` translates port numbers to service names in its output, so you have to look for ":mysql" instead of ":3306".)

Comment: thanks. somewhere along the line the server started up again. Why do you think this is repeatedly happening? Are the above files being corrupted?

Comment: use ps -ef | grep mysqld and kill any mysqld process running.

Comment: Having a similar issue but I do not see a solution here. There is no other mysql currently running on my machine, I did this as well to stop any mysql instances sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop

Comment: Not much of an answer here. Would be nice to have some notes on resources or tools on how to resolve with instructions.

Comment: @frshjb373 It's impossible to give exact instructions; there's a lot of different ways that a MySQL server could be set up (on multiple different operating systems!) which would cause this problem.

Comment: @duskwuff, I gotchya...just surprised so many upvotes for this. I resolved by force quitting mysqld processes in Activity Monitor several times, then powering off MAMP Pro and shutting down, waiting a bit and turned back on. Finally worked after several tries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what fixed it for me, looked all around and nothing helped.

To fix this issue, make a copy of the original files (ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1…).

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1.bak

cp -a /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1.bak /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
```

Now start mysql service.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

In my case it was the XAMPP files so I did

```
sudo mv /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ibdata1 /Users/username/Documents/tmp/ibdata1.bak
sudo cp -a /Users/username/Documents/tmp/ibdata1.bak /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ibdata1
```

Then I noticed that mysql was already started for me.

Based on the solution [here](http://www.webhostingsupport.info/innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-error-11/)