# MYSQL Command Startup Error

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I ran this command:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

from terminal without fully understanding it like a dummy (trying to get mysql server to start automatically on boot) and know I can't access mysql at all.

I get this error:

```
2016-01-11 17:26:52 551 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1,    
error: 35
2016-01-11 17:26:52 551 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

Can someone explain what I did?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to the executed command. What you did is creating soft/symbolic links (something like shortcut) to plist files that are used to manage MySQL services. You can simply use `unlink` command to unlink them (**It's not recommended unless you know which file can be unlinked without any side effects**).

So your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33746682/777769).